# How to integrate paytm wallet in android application

Tags: android, integration, paytm

I am trying to integrate paytm wallet in android application , I am not understanding what should I give parameter in following function

```
 PaytmMerchant Merchant = new PaytmMerchant(<ChecksumGenerator>,<ValidateChksum>);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
PaytmMerchant Merchant = new PaytmMerchant(String  inChecksumGenerationURL, String inChecksumVerificationURL);
```

where
`inChecksumGenerationURL` is the Merchant Checksum Generation URL and
`inChecksumVerificationURL` Merchant Checksum Verification URL

Hope [this](https://paytm-wallet-sdk.readme.io/docs/steps-1) will help you with integration.